# Vulnerability Assessments - Vulnerability Taxonomies?

Tags: terminology

All,

First question on here so please be as gentle as you can :-)

I've been looking around for any writings or papers on a standard for classifying vulnerabilities.  Not from a severity/risk/impact point of view but categorising such as grouping all the 'missing patches',  'weak authentication management',  egress/ingress rules for networks and alike.  Now I know that plenty of people have done this work already, myself included.  What I am interested to know is if anyone has done something on a more formal/standard footing?

Long question, all responses warmly welcomed.

Comment: Hi @IC3N1, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MITRE has a few systems for this. CVE for things that need patching; CWE for bugs that need to be avoided/fixed, CAPEC describing attacks to your infrastructure; CCE for configuration needs; CPE for a proper naming scheme; and CEE for event exchange information.

http://makingsecuritymeasurable.mitre.org

You'll find links to other resources that work along with MITRE's standards or are similar in nature to them.

Comment: Yup, I was going to point to MITRE, though it seems that CWE is more what the OP was looking for...

Comment: Just as a follow up - MITRE looks like it is my friend.  Many thanks.

Comment: There has been a lot of great work on this in the past 7 years. This list from MISP/circl is a great place to start: https://www.circl.lu/doc/misp-taxonomies/

Answer (score 2):

The OWASP top ten categorisation is exactly this kind of thing. Admittedly, they have chosen to dramatically shrink scope to just the top ten attack types.

Comment: OWASP Top 10 is good for those that it includes, and OWASP has a larger library of common vulnerabilities (though I guess not as formalized as MITRE's), mostly donated by Fortify and Aspect (so take them with certain amount of sodium chloride...)

Comment: Rory, thanks for the answer. Although the OWASP list gives good coverage of the common vulnerabilities it is by it's very nature web centric.  For my needs I wanted a broader set of categories and I think MITRE's work looks closer to my needs.